# python 3: type inferencing with mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-inference, type-hinting, mypy

Given the following snippet in python 3

```
def foo() -> List[X]: pass

class X:
    def bar(self) -> MYTYPE: pass
```

for the following expression:

`[x.bar() for x in foo()]`

Can I utilize `mypy` package to correctly parse the AST of the expression above and guess the type of the result is `List[MYTYPE]`?

If can not, what's my best choice? any ideas/packages to recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will infer it. Here's a demo:

```
from typing import List

class MyType:
    pass

class X:
    def bar(self) -> MyType: pass

def foo() -> List[X]: pass  # note the square brackets

bars = [x.bar() for x in foo()]
reveal_type(bars)
```

Then when you run `mypy script.py` in a terminal you will see a message:

```
Revealed type is 'builtins.list[script.MyType*]'
```

Documentation about `reveal_type` [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#reveal-type).

By the way there was a small problem with your code, it should be `List[X]` not `List(X)`.

PyCharm will also recognise the types. `bars.` will give autocomplete options for list methods, and `bars[0].` will give options for `MyType`.